# req.body.name is undefined error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read form-data sent using postman. Here is the code !!

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/action', function(req, res) {      
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
});
app.listen(8074);
```

Output: You sent the name undefined

Why is the name not being printed ? I have followed all procedures in the net but couldn't find the answer ...
Where am i wrong ??

Here is screenshot tells about what i do in postman

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've ticked the "form-data" box instead of the "x-www-form-urlencoded" box in Postman, but you've used the `urlencoded` body parser in your JS.

You need to match the body parser to the encoding method you use.

Comment: Ohh you saved me !!! Now i see .... I am new to postman so cound not notice it !!  Thanks man ... I have been stuck at this for 3hrs

Comment: It should be in querystring param now. Always console log everything and find what you're looking for. When in doubt, do `require( "util" ).inspect( obj, { showHidden: true, depth: null } );` then start reading!